# How to input Foreign Key in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have some problem in here, so i have a 3 table

The relation of this table is one to many

Facility (1) -> (Many) TD_Facility
T_Transaksi (1) -> (Many) TD_Facility

I try to post some data in TD_Facility and this is the source code

Controller td_facility.js (i put create function only in here, if i put all code it will be a long code ehehe)

```
let fasilitas   = req.body.id_fasilitas,
      jenisHarga  = req.body.type_harga,
      harga = req.body.harga
  try {
    let objList = {
      fasilitas_id:fasilitas,
      type_harga:jenisHarga,
      total_harga:harga,
      t_transaksi_id:penjualan,
    }
    // console.log(objList);
    await modelTDFasilitas.create(objList)
    }catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({
          status:'FAIL - Gagal memasukan Fasilitas ke List',
          msg:'Something happen with the server'
        })
      }
```

and this is the relation on model Facility.js and T_Transaksi.js

Facility.js

```
Facility.hasOne(td_facility,{foreignKey:'fasilitas_id'})
Facility.hasMany(td_facility,{foreignKey:'fasilitas_id'})
```

T_Transaksi.js

```
T_Penjualan.hasOne(td_facility,{foreignKey:'t_transaksi_id'})
T_Penjualan.hasMany(td_facility,{foreignKey:'t_transaksi_id'})
```

When i try post somedata, it **only** returning id_td_fasilitas","type_harga","total_harga","fasilitas_id";

Where is t_transaksi_id ? Why i am not getting an any error message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when working with relations, you work with each model individually, then link the instances of the models.

See the doc : https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html

Read the doc, if you still don’t understand, ask me, I will explain you.

Lukas.

Comment: Hello Lukas, i have read the doc very carefuly but it's still doesn't work.

If i want to make 1 to many relationship, i must use A.hasMany(B) to declare foreign key in B, it must be work, but it's not ~

Comment: Ok, no problem, I will take the example of a team. You need first to have a player on your team, and a player belongs to a team do you do : Player.belongsTo(Team). And because a team has players, you do Team.hasMany(Player). Here’s a quick example of how to declare associations, you can include the player model when fetching a team to get the team players. If it is still not clear for you, ask what you need and i’ll answer.